# Moving Wordpress from host without FTP?

Tags: plugins, admin, hosting, ftp, clone-site

I have a website hosted with service A which do not provide FTP access, and I would like to move it to another host B which provides FTP access. Is there any way to move?

Traditional Archive,Download, and Upload is useless, since site is pretty large(2 GB).

I've tried getting some most-popular plugins, but none seems to do the job. Also `max_execution_time` is 30 secs

Any suggestions?

Comment: your situation doesn't make much sense. How do you install plugins in the first place without FTP access?

Comment: What does FTP got to do with installing plugins? WP was installed directly from Cpanel, and I was able to install plugins right from Wordpress Admin menu...

Comment: and how did you edit your theme, or did you just reuploded the theme after each change? OK better question which hosting service is it that do not give you an ftp access?

Comment: I've been using the inbuilt Editor in Appearance>Editor, and everything seems fine till now. You sound like you haven't used WordPress before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case - i will suggest you to use this plugin :

http://codecanyon.net/item/super-backup-clone-migrate-for-wordpress/12943030

This plugin can make the backup of the site on  Google drive,Dropbox amazon and etc, and after that you can sync your site with cloud (your old site and new site will be connected via cloud). So you don't need to download and upload the site again.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, I've got the files on Dropbox, but couldn't upload it back to the new host due to fair large size

Comment: Did you tried to upload it from FTP ?

Comment: Yes, but it fails due to timeout...

Comment: Upload it in chunks ! Don't you have hosting/cPanel login  of new host?

Comment: Is there any cloud-to-cloud transfer options available in my case?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31751/discussion-between-daniyalahmad-and-snazzy-sanoj).